# Trying to pass a variable to CTkComboBox from a sqlite query

Tags: python, variables, combobox

I'm a relative newbie with regard to Python, however, I wanted to create a custom budgeting program to gain some more practice and exposure.  I have the following class so far -

```py
class NewAccountEntryFrame(CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, master, cursor):
        super().__init__(master=master)
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.account_types = []
        print("self.account_types", self.account_types) #debugging line to make sure the self.account_types is empty at this point

        self.frame_label = CTkLabel(master=self, text="New Account Entry", font=("Arial", 30))
        self.frame_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.new_account_label = CTkLabel(master=self, text="Enter New Account Name:")
        self.new_account_label.pack(pady=5)

        self.new_account_entry = CTkEntry(master=self, width=30)
        self.new_account_entry.pack(pady=5)
        self.new_account_entry.bind("<Return>", self.add_account)
        
        self.new_account_type_label = CTkLabel(master=self, text="Enter New Account Type:")
        self.new_account_type_label.pack(pady=5)

        self.new_account_type_combobox = CTkComboBox(master=self,  width=30)
        self.new_account_type_combobox.pack(pady=5)
        self.new_account_type_combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.on_click)
       
        self.new_account_add_button = CTkButton(master=self, text="Add")
        self.new_account_add_button.pack(pady=10)
```

Once a new_account_entry is entered, I'm calling the following function that checks to see if the name is an existing one in an `AccountName` table:

```
def add_account(self, event):
        new_account_name = self.new_account_entry.get()
        if not new_account_name:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter an account name.")
            return

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE AccountName = ?", (new_account_name,))
        existing_account = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if existing_account:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Account already exists.")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Account is not in the database. Please select an account type.")
            self.update_account_types()
```

So, now is where I'm struggling.  I call the `update_account_types()` function, which pulls the list of `AccountTypes` from the `AccountType` table:

```
def update_account_types(self):
        print("Fetching Account Types...")
        account_types = [row[0] for row in self.cursor.execute("SELECT AccountType FROM AccountType   ORDER BY AccountType")]
        
        print ("account types", account_types) #Prints out the account_types from the database as expected
        self.account_types = account_types
        
        print("self.account_types", self.account_types)  #prints out the account_types from the database as expected
```

so now my `self.account_types` variable has values in my class above, however, when I click on the `new_account_type_combobox`, the only value I see is `CTkComboBox`

I was able to get the `combobox` to populate correctly before I added the `add_account` function to check if an `account_name` already existed in the database.

I can print out the `account_types` to the screen, however, they are not populating the combo box.

Comment: you have to `.append()` or maybe  `.insert()` new values to `new_account_type_combobox` . `GUI` will not do it for you.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create `minimal working code` with example data directly in code - so we could simply copy and text it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Documentation: [CTkComboBox](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/combobox)

GUI will not add it automatically to widget. You have to use `.configure(values=...)`

```
self.new_account_type_combobox.configure(values=["new value 1", "new value 2"])
```

In your code it can means `values=self.account_types`

```
self.new_account_type_combobox.configure(values=self.account_types)
```

And you have to do it always when you get new values from database.
So you have to do it in `update_account_types()`